# Match string with number range at the end

Tags: regex, string, match

I'm checking for serial ports and I only want to use ones that match "COM1-4".
I could not figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding a bit on Tim's answer:

If you want to match a specific range of characters, you can use `[]` notation - for numbers, you can say `[1-4]` to match (characters) `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, or `'4'`.

If you want a number at the end of a string, you mark "end of string" with the `$` sign.

Finally, if you have a piece of "normal" text that you want to match exactly, you use that string. Note that if your string contains characters that have special meaning for `regex` (things like `.`, `\`. `+`, `()`, `[]`, etc) you need to be more careful.

When you want to match "only this in the string and nothing else", you use the anchors for "start of string" `^` and "end of string" `$` to surround your expression.

This is how you end up with

```
^COM[1-4]$
```

for *exactly* one of `COM1`, `COM2`, `COM3`, or `COM4`.

If you could have other things before, leave off the `^`.

Answer (score 2):

This is trivial:

```
^COM[1-4]$
```

See this tutorial about [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).